# Remove all cookies except for app/pinned tabs

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, cookie

Is there a way to remove all cookies, on shutdown, of any websites not pinned? Manually adding websites to the exception list isn't straightforward since some websites saves multiple cookies from different domains.

I'm looking for a solution for either Chrome/Chromium or Firefox.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

To see what cookies a particular site sets, the [View Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/view-cookies/) Firefox Add-On can help. That or just open the sites you want to pin one at a time to see which cookies get set. Then pin them all and set your cookie policies.  From there, you can go back to manually whitelisting or use the [Cookies Manager Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/?src=ss) Add-On to do it for you. For example, I've used these in the past to identify and whitelist the Google two-factor authentication cookie that remembers you for 30 days, while still deleting all other cookies when I close Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Biscuit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220876/) extension for Firefox. It allows you to select which cookies you want to preserve, so when Firefox closes, it deletes only the cookies not protected.

Comment: Yes, you suggested this to me on a previous answer, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem of figuring out all the cookies I need to preserve.

Comment: Well, perhaps not al of them, but at least you know the domain. Just protect the ones of the pinned domains.

Comment: That's the problem, protecting just the domains of pinned websites are not enough. A good example is Gmail - besides cookies for mail.google.com, there are other cookies from google.com or even youtube.com. I wish there was some automatic methods to find which ones to keep.

Comment: I keep all google, gmail and youtube.